# MYSQL table join deduct data

Tags: php, mysql

I m building a simplified social networking site in php. I have two tables, myfriends table and friends table.

myfriends table has `friend_id1` and `friend_id2` columns. Friends table has `friend_id`,`profile_name` and `email` columns.

The myfriends table links 2 friends together. Assume a uni directional relationship, instead of bidirectional. This means friend_id1 has a friend friend_id2 but not vice versa.

To illustrate lets just take only 4 members `1001,1002,1003,1004`

If 1001 knows 1002 and 1003 (and assuming vice versa) but 1002, 1003 don’t know each other and 1004 does not know anyone, the myfriends table will have the following entries.

```
(1001,1002),(1001 ,1003),(1002 ,1001),(1003, 1001)
```

I need query that will get all the people who are not friends.This the query that i have come up with to get all the friends.friend_id is the primary key of the friends `table.myfriends` table doesnt have a primary key.

```
 SELECT friends.profile_name 
 FROM friends 
 INNER JOIN myfriends ON friends.friend_id=myfriends.friend_id1 
 WHERE myfriends.friend_id2='$friendID'";
```

Hope the question is clear to you all.

Comment: You want to query all people who are not friend with specified person, right?

Comment: Do you want to get those who do not have friend right?In above scenario, 1004 should be the result?

Comment: Your Question is ambiguous, Do you want to get all people who don't have a friend(record not in myfriends table) or You want to get peoples who is not friend with (people=x) ??

Comment: i want to get all the people who are not friends with a given person.For example above when i select 1003, it need to show 1002's profile name only.since 1001 is friends with both 1002 and 1003.mutual friendship is show like (1001,1002)(1002 ,1001)/(1001 ,1003)(1003, 1001).

Comment: i want to get all the people who are not friends with 1003 but already in the system.Kinda like the Facebook's friend suggestions.

Comment: Litte correction for my previous comment."when i select 1003,it needs to show 1002 and 1004's profile names."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$sql="select profile_name from friends
>
>            where friend_id<>login_user_id
>
>   and
>
>   friend_id NOT IN( select friend_id2 from myfriends where friend_id1=login_user_id);`

Comment: its not working.My query gives me all the mutual friends in a persons profile.I just need some how to deduct all of them from the friends table which has all the registered members to get all the people who are not a friend of that person.

Comment: let me clear a little bit what u actually want tell me about scenario of ur work lettle bit clear

Comment: you want that when i enter into someone profile i will show him the profile name of the persons which are not his friends... is it you want

Comment: when the user logged in to the system and wants to add new friends he goes to a page called "Add friends". A list of all the people who are not friends with him will be shown there.I need to get that profile name list.Hope this is clear enough for you.

Comment: yes now will make a query for you but wait a little because em in office see you soon

Comment: So now this is a generic query for u just copy paste it. if work than vote up

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant solution to this but here goes:

```
SELECT f.profile_name 
FROM friends f 
WHERE 
    f.id <> 1004 AND 
    f.id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT mf.friend_1 
        FROM myfriends mf 
        WHERE 
            mf.friend_1 = 1004 AND 
            mf.friend_2 = 1004
    ) AND 
    f.id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT mf2.friend_2 
        FROM myfriends mf2 
        WHERE 
            mf2.friend_1 = 1004 OR 
            mf2.friend_2 = 1004
    );
```

This seems to give the result you desire.